# split and readline in Python - list index out of range

Tags: python, indexing, split, readline

```
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftLearning/intropython/master/worl
d_temp_mean.csv -o mean_temp.txt
weather = open('mean_temp.txt','a+')
weather.write('Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0\n"')
weather.seek(0)
headings = weather.readline()
apple = headings.split(',')
city_temp = weather.readline()
orange = city_temp.split(',')
while city_temp:
    orange = city_temp.split(',')
    print (apple[2] + ' of ' + orange[1] + ' is ' + orange[2] + ' Celsius')
    city_temp = weather.readline()
weather.close()
```

I don't understand why there is an error:

> list index out of range

in the output. I have tried to separate the readline and split for ensuring the while loop only receive the string.

Comment: can you post the error traceback too

Comment: Your question has been flagged for low quality, and I am writing to you as a reviewer. (1) It would be helpful to anyone who wants to answer your question if you could show some of the contents of the input file, `mean_temp.txt`. (2) Using names like `apple` and `orange` makes your code harder to read. For instance, for `apple` you could use `heading_items` instead. (3) I agree with @KalyanReddy.

Answer (score 0):

When you're appending to your file, you end up like this:

```
city,country,month ave: highest high,month ave: lowest low
Beijing,China,30.9,-8.4
Cairo,Egypt,34.7,1.2
London,UK,23.5,2.1
Nairobi,Kenya,26.3,10.5
New York City,USA,28.9,-2.8
Sydney,Australia,26.5,8.7
Tokyo,Japan,30.8,0.9Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0
"
```

The line you're adding is appending to the end of the last line and not on a new line. So you get an out of range index because you don't have those indices on the last line of your file.

Trying appending a carriage return before adding the new line.

Comment: This is not correct. The downloaded file is already terminated by a newline. The actual problem is caused by a typo which adds a `"` to the string which is written to the file. This creates an extra line which splits into a list with only one element, when the program is expecting four.